# Using QT on Linux, is there a way to disable "Always on Top"?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, always-on-top

My problem: A QT 4 C++ application, to run on Linux, needs to lock down all sorts of routine GUI functionality.  Specifically, I want to remove as much of the functionality of the title bar as I can.

I was able to do most of that using
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint);

But there remains a drop-down menu from the upper-left corner of the title bar.  Most of the functions inside are disabled (no min, max or close), but the "always on top" check-box is enabled.

Can I disable the "Always On Top" check-box through QT or do I need to find an OS workaround?

Comment: Just a friendly advice, I wouldn't use a software that would block functions like that.

Comment: @OneOfOne I know what you mean, but he's not asking you to use it. There may be a legitimate reason for wanting this (a low-security kiosk or educational application perhaps).

Comment: You could have the window be without a titlebar and provide the user an alternate means to move/close the window.

Comment: @OneOfOne I don't disagree, but my client does.  I should have phrased this as a "requirement" and not a "want".

For that matter, I'm not entirely opposed to going back to the client and saying "you gave me a requirement that requires effort outside of the limits and budget you gave me", but I must do due-diligence and investigate my options first.

Comment: Qt::FramelessWindow or some similar flag may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window title is handled by the window manager. Qt cannot change the title of the window directly. It can only use different hints and native API to ask the window manager to do what you want (remove specific buttons etc.). The window manager can decline your request. So the only 100% working solution is to use Qt::FramelessWindowHint and draw your own window decorations by hand.

Comment: Accepting this because it does fix the problem, though it feels like using a club when a scalpel was called for.  However it doesn't seem QT can do this in a more elegant way.